pyinstaller creates .exe but it fails with "module not found"
When creating a simple executable (Windows) with pyinstaller, my py script can be compiled, but when starting it, it fails with:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "salsatest.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "salsa20.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "imp.py", line 297, in find_module
ImportError: No module named '_salsa20'

The script itself runs without any problems by doing
python salsatest.py

Here is the simple python script salsatest.py
from salsa20 import XSalsa20_xor
from os import urandom
IV = urandom(24)
KEY = b'secretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecret'
ciphertext = XSalsa20_xor(b"IT'S A YELLOW SUBMARINE", IV, KEY[0:32])
print(ciphertext)
print(XSalsa20_xor(ciphertext, IV, KEY[0:32]).decode()) 

I am using pyinstaller version 6.6.0 and python Python 3.11.9
The salsa library was installed before with
pip install salsa20
I created the .exe with
pyinstaller --onefile salsatest.py

